# How to Compute Var($4X-Y$) on this case?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

> Let $X$ be the number of $1$'s and $Y$ be the number of $2$'s that occur in $n$
>   rolls of a fair die.

$(a)$ Compute Cov($X; Y$ ).

---

Solution are given in other post: [Compute Cov(X,Y) while X is the number of 1's and Y is the number of 2's in n dice rolls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611860/compute-covx-y-while-x-is-the-number-of-1s-and-y-is-the-number-of-2s-in-n-di)

or problem $7.36$ 
at, http://www.stat.washington.edu/~hoytak/teaching/current/stat395/

---

Part (B): Compute Var($4X-Y$)

I use the hint below,

$4X-Y$= Z

Then,

E[Z^2]= sum of all x and y of { (Z^2) P(x=i,y=j)}

and

E[Z]= sum of all x and y of { (Z) P(x=i,y=j)}

And Var($4X-Y$)=E[Z^2]-(E[Z])^2

But, I don't understand what values I plug to compute each terms. Thanks!

Comment: Note that $\text{Var}[4X - Y] \neq 16 \text{Var}[X] + \text{Var}[Y]$, as the two are not uncorrelated! If you've actually understood how to calculate the covariance, then the specific variances are not harder than that, and should be within your reach. Start out with $$P\{X = i, Y = j \} = \binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{j} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{i+j} \left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{(n - i -j)}$$

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand how to use your hint in the computation of the variance. Could you expand your hint? Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just use the formula $Var(X+Y) = Var(X)+Var(Y) + 2Cov(X,Y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you calculated/understood part (a). Then, ignoring the hint,
$$\text{Var}(4X-Y) = 16\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)-2\cdot 4\text{Cov}(X,Y),$$
using known properties of variance and covariance.

If you really wanted to use that "hint", you'd have to calculate the distribtion of $Z$. That seems like too much work if you are just looking for the answer.

Comment: I have E(X)=nx and E(Y)=nx and Cov(x,y) from part a. But how I can calculate E(x^2)=(Y^2) ? Is this 1/36 (each) ? and then I plug in your ecuation (statment) and I'm done? or are any other procces that I can not see. Thanks for your response Probablyme.

Comment: I see your problem now! I do not think you have to take this approach. You have to recognize that $X$ is a known distribution. So is $Y$. What are they? If you recognize the distribution of $X$, then you know the variance of $X$. The same is true for $Y$. In this manner, you can skip trying to calculate for example $\text{E}[X^2]$.

Comment: If I don't missunderstand X and Y are binomial, with variance np(1-p), p=1/6 each , I know cov(x,y) and I get the final answer, is that rigth?

Comment: Yes! Recognizing distributions like this can save you a lot of work, especially on more complicated problems.